# How to get the column name from a query?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
City   Obesity   Asthma   Diabetes
London 403221    412331   445121
Paris  104221    211227   201771
Berlin 322128    365119   309233
...    ...       ...      ...
```

I want to get the name of city and the name of the demise that is the most common.
I can get the max value using `df.groupby("City")[["Obesity", "Asthma", "Diabetes"]].sum().max(axis=1)` which gives something like this:

```
City
London  445121
Paris   211227
Berlin  365119
...
```

What I want would look like this:

```
City
London  Diabetes
Paris   Asthma
Berlin  Asthma
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `idxmax`

```
df.groupby("City")[["Obesity", "Asthma", "Diabetes"]].sum().idxmax(axis=1)
```

If city names are unique then use

```
df.set_index('City').idxmax(axis=1)
```